# learnr: How to invalidate stored worked locally by changing ID and version?

Tags: r, yaml, version, uuid, learnr

I am developing tutorials with the `learnr` package. During the iterative testing process, I would need to invalidate the tutorial file.

I followed the explanation from [Preserving Work](https://rstudio.github.io/learnr/#preserving_work), added ID and version to the yaml header.

But whenever I changed ID and/or the version number, I always got my last exercise trial.

> When you change the ID or version of a tutorial all stored work associated with the tutorial is invalidated and users of the tutorial will start fresh when accessing it again. (from [Preserving Work](https://rstudio.github.io/learnr/#preserving_work))

The above quote did not work for me: Even if I restarted RStudio and/or used `Clear Rendered Output …` resp. `Clear Knitr Cache …`. But I did succeed in changing the label of the chunk header(s) and I know I could use the "Start Over" button at the tutorial page.

Could it be that ID and version do not work locally? (BTW: Where are the files with the stored work associated with the tutorial on my computer?)

My yaml header looks like:

```
---
title: "Tutorial"
tutorial:
  id: "b4e9e9b1-02b1-45c7-b35e-64ff6fbf0a0e"
  version: 2.9
output: 
    learnr::tutorial:
        progressive: true
        allow_skip: true
runtime: shiny_prerendered
---
```

I am using the `uuid` package to generate IDs - as mentioned in the `learnr` tutorial under [Tutorial Identifiers](https://rstudio.github.io/learnr/#preserving_work).

I start a new trial always with the command `rmarkdown::run("<path-to-filename/filname>")`.

---

This question should tagged with `learnr`, but I do not have the privileges to create a new tag.

Answer (score 1):

@jjallaire answered my question on [Github](https://github.com/rstudio/learnr/issues/165):

> Locally stored work doesn't use the ID unfortunately. Local tutorial
>   storage can be found at:
>
> `file.path(rappdirs::user_data_dir(), "R", "learnr", "tutorial",
>   "storage")`

Answer (score 0):

This does not answer the exact question, but if one wants to start fresh after each change to the tutorial (to see the new changes in the tutorial), one way would be to add a file called `restart.txt` in the directory where the tutorial's `.Rmd` file is and after each change to the tutorial before loading the tutorial, one needs to run `touch restart.txt` to update `restart.txt`'s the modification time. This tells the `shiny` server to start fresh.